# Why does SSL Web access work as root in an interactive shell, but not as user `apache` in a post-commit script?

Tags: perl, unix, ssl

I have a Perl program, intended to be run from a subversion `post-commit` script, which needs to connect to a HTTPS based Web API.

When I test the program from an interactive shell, as root, it works just fine.

When it runs from the `post-commit` script, it errors out, and the response from LWP is along the lines of "500 Connect failed".

There's some evidence that when run from the `post-commit` script, SS isn't enabled, because when I set `$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} =1;` and run it as root, I see debug output, such as

> SSL_connect:before/connect initialization

but from the `post-commit` script, non of the SLL debug info is printed.

- The the `post-commit` script runs as user `apache`.
- I'm running CentOS 64bit.

It's been years since I've done any Unix work, so I'm not sure what the next steps are to get SSL working in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run this:

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=on
```

to allow the httpd process to make network connections

Answer (score 2):

The difference in environments makes me suspicious.  Like running cron jobs, it may be that the environment, the INC path, or the perl interpreter itself is sufficiently different that it can't find Crypt::SSLeay or whatever else you're using for SSL support.

As a troubleshooting step, try using this program in both your shell and in the post-commit hook to see if there is an environment difference between the two.  This will dump several runtime variables that show what perl knows about its environment to a tempfile.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;
use File::Temp qw( tempfile );
use strict;
use warnings;

my $tempdir = '/tmp';            # Change this if necessary.

my( $fh, $fname ) = tempfile( "tempXXXXXX", DIR => $tempdir, UNLINK => 0 );
print $fh Data::Dumper->Dump( [ \@INC, \%INC, $^X, $0, $], \@ARGV, \%ENV ],
                              [ qw( @INC %INC ^X 0 ] @ARGV %ENV ] ) ] );
close( $fh );

# Change this if the post-commit hook doesn't pass stdout back to you.
print "Wrote data to $fname.\n";

__END__
```

If they differ substantially, your next step would be to make the environment in the post-commit hook the same as under your shell, e.g. adding a `use lib qw( /path/to/where/ssl/modules/are/installed );` line to your script's `use` section, by setting `PERL5LIB`, using the full path to a different Perl interpreter,  or whatever is appropriate.  See `perldoc perlvar` for a description of some of the variables, if you're not familiar with them.

Comment: Great suggestion. The `@INC` and `$INC` vars are the same for both. The %ENV is different of course, but nothing in %ENV, other than the PATH seems to mean anything. Setting PATH didn't help.

Comment: Well, then I'd probably bust out `strace` or a network sniffer at this point (wireshark, snort, etc). to either trace the system calls (in both the shell and the post-commit hook, probably mediated by a shell script), and/or check what's going on over the network connection to get the `500` status code.

Comment: (It might be `truss`, `trace`, or something else on your UNIX platform.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Perl issue.  Perl is doing only what it is told.  Figure out what is saying "http:" vs "https:" above Perl, and sort that out.  You don't need to "configure Perl... to use SSL".

Comment: The same code is running in both situations, what, other than the code, is telling Perl what to do?